# Nest for elastic search 5.1 how make a basic aggs?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In NEST  Elastic Search 5.1 I would like to be able to make a basic aggs equivalent of this http direct request which works:

```
POST  /base_well/person/_search
{
    "aggs": {
        "all_words" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "Age"                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It give me this answere:

```
{
   "took": 22,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlMAnskcR_Z5VPUXUCs",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "Polo",
               "last_name": "Rodriguez",
               "Age": 36
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlMAo0NcR_Z5VPUXUCu",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "Mustapha",
               "last_name": "Bulutu M'Bo",
               "Age": 26
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlMAnPFcR_Z5VPUXUCr",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "James",
               "last_name": "Mopo",
               "Age": 21
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlMAoO8cR_Z5VPUXUCt",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "Marc Aurelien",
               "last_name": "Poisson",
               "Age": 26
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "all_words": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 26,
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": 21,
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": 36,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I did this c# nest attempt:

```
 public class Person
  {
        public string first_name {get;set;}
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
  }

 var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
  var setting = new ConnectionSettings(uri);
  setting.DisableDirectStreaming(true);
  setting.DefaultIndex("base_well");
  var Client = new ElasticClient(setting);


  var response = Client.Search<Person>(s => s
                                       .Type("person")
                                       .Aggregations(p => p
                                       .Terms(ageCodeAggregation, m => m
                                       .Field(f => f.Age))));
```

But it give me an empty result:

[image]

I Give you sample for context:

I create index and mapping with:

```
PUT /base_well
{
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
               "properties": {
                   "first_name":{
                       "type": "string",
                       "store": true
                   },
                     "last_name":{
                       "type": "string",
                      "store": true
                   },
                   "Age":{
                       "type": "long",
                       "store": true
                   }
               }
        }
    }
}
```

I populate :

```
  POST /base_well/person
        {
            "first_name":"James",
            "last_name" : "Mopo",
            "Age" : 21
        }

    POST /base_well/person
    {
        "first_name":"Polo",
        "last_name" : "Rodriguez",
        "Age" : 36
    }

    POST /base_well/person
    {
        "first_name":"Marc Aurelien",
        "last_name" : "Poisson",
        "Age" : 26
    }

    POST /base_well/person
    {
        "first_name":"Mustapha",
        "last_name" : "Bulutu M'Bo",
        "Age" : 26
    }
```

Anybody could explain me to do it and how it works please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEST by default camelcases field names when serializing C# POCO property names and sending them to Elasticsearch. So, `.Field(f => f.Age)` will serialize to `"age"` but the field in Elasticsearch is `"Age"`, so no results are returned.

In order to change the field name serialization behaviour, you can pass a delegate to `DefaultFieldNameInferrer()` on `ConnectionSettings`

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var setting = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
    .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(s => s)
    .DefaultIndex("base_well");

var client = new ElasticClient(setting);
```

Since you want your POCO property names reflected verbatim in the field names sent to Elasticsearch, the delegate just returns the property name to use as the string for the field name.

Comment: Thank you for tip ! but it  work in same way  even with your fix and even by replacing Age by age everywhere (in es, in Person Class and in code)

Comment: sorry You were right, thank you very mutch , there are not a lot of people able to answere on this topic